# I need to rotate a face created using I without effecting the geometry of the other vertex of the object

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, vertices, geometry

I am creating a human figure for animation following series of you tube tutorial from 'Blender Character Modelling Tutorial - Body Modelling for Beginners'.
While I am doing the hand, I manage to create the fingernails face using 'i' keystroke.
Now I want to rotate the fingernail faces without changing the geomancy of any vertex of the finger as same as the video does it. But when I do it change the finger.

This is the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSluNGHUevk
Please see the 19:20 to 20:00 in the timeline.

I will attach a picture of my works so far as well.

Comment: In the Transform Pivot Point panel he chooses Individual Origins and also he disables the Proportional Editing option (press O), otherwise it will affect the adjacent vertices

Comment: You haven't added the image of your work to your question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. As @moonboots says, he has Individual Origins selected in the Pivot Point settings and Proportional Editing disabled (toggled with the 'O' key).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, it was 'O' for the propositional editing was enabled. Once, propositional editing is disabled, that worked. However, I was unable to find how to do the 'Transform Pivot Point panel' or 'Pivot Point settings' change.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Transform Pivot Point* panel he chooses *Individual Origins* and also he disables the *Proportional Editing* option (press <kbd>O</kbd>), otherwise it will affect the adjacent vertices:

[image]